# Data returning as nil after passing through protocol to next view controller

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, segue, protocols

I am presenting a view controller modally as a custom popover from a table view using `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` and `prepareForSegue`.  However, the data on the next view controller is returning nil.  I have narrowed the problem down to passing the data through the protocol itself.  Below I will include the relevant code for both view controllers and the log.

**First View Controller:**

```
protocol barTableViewControllerDelegate {
    func acceptData(data: AnyObject!)
}

class barTableViewController: UITableViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    var delegate: barTableViewControllerDelegate?
    var data: AnyObject?

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        print("yes")
        let classIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!
        print(classIndexPath.row)
        print("yes2")
        let selectedClass = names[classIndexPath.row]
        print("yes3")
        print(names[classIndexPath.row])
        self.delegate?.acceptData(selectedClass)
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showAd", sender: self)
    }


    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if(segue.identifier == "showAd") {
            /* if let objIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row {
            let obj = queryArray[objIndexPath]
            let navVC = segue.destinationViewController as! UINavigationController
            let detailVC = navVC.topViewController as! DetailViewController
            detailVC.post = obj */
            print("is segue working")
            let popOverVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("adPopUp") as! PopUpViewController
            self.addChildViewController(popOverVC)
            popOverVC.view.frame = self.view.frame
            self.view.addSubview(popOverVC.view)
            popOverVC.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
            print("segue working")
        }
    }
```

**Second View Controller:**

```
class PopUpViewController: UIViewController {

    func acceptData(data: AnyObject!) {
        self.post = data! as! String
    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print("here")
        print(post)
        print(self.post)
        print("here2")
    }
}
```

[log screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hzXkS.png)

The last log printed is `here.` Stops at `print(post)`.
I don't think I have to declare data in the second view controller?

Comment: Is `acceptData` method called? It's possible that `delegate` in `barTableViewController` is nil.

Comment: @Eluss acceptData method is declared in the protocol in the first view controller above the class.  It is called in the second view controller above the viewDidLoad method.  Could you please elaborate on how/why the delegate in barTableViewController is nil?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're going **forward**, you don't need the protocol. You can simply set the next view controller's variable in `prepareForSegue`

```
class barTableViewController: UITableViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {        

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        let classIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!
        let selectedClass = names[classIndexPath.row]
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showAd", sender: self)
    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if(segue.identifier == "showAd") {
            let popOverVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("adPopUp") as! PopUpViewController

            popOverVC.data = selectedClass  // <-- Set the variable in the next VC

            self.addChildViewController(popOverVC)
            popOverVC.view.frame = self.view.frame
            self.view.addSubview(popOverVC.view)
            popOverVC.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
        }
    }
}

class PopUpViewController: UIViewController {

    var data: String!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if let passedData = data {
            self.post = passedData
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: such a simple solution and it worked perfectly.  Thank you for the clarification

Comment: @boppa You're welcome. If you want to pass the data backward, like when you dismiss the popup, you would use a delegate

Answer (score 0):

The way you use segue is wrong, you should not initialise the `popOverVC` in `prepareForSegue`, also you should not do view transitioning(`setFrame`, `addSubview`) in `prepareForSegue` as well. `UIStoryboardSegue` has a property called `destinationViewController`, which in your case is the `popOverVC`. And if you want to do custom transitions between the source(`barTableViewController`) and destination(`popOverVC`), you need to subclass `UIStoryboardSegue`, override its `perform` method, and do everything there.